Spring boot API is taking >12 seconds to respond
I am using Java Spring boot in the backend service and database is MSSql.
I am working on an API that performs data aggregation and returns the result. After the result has been returned I am using java code to do the final setup of the data before sending it as a response.
This entire process is taking around 12 seconds if I fetch the data for the single month. If I select the 6 month data it is taking forever and will never response to me back.
Initially I was using JPA but than I switched to the native query approach which reduced some time but 12 seconds for 30 days of data processing is still way way way to much. I want to reduce the time it is taking.
I came up with the 2 things

Caching
Database indexing

I have my hands tied at the database as I can not switch from MSSql to any other database like NoSql or anything.
I need some guidance on caching strategy and how to reduce the API response time.
Below my SQL query:
WITH DateRange AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, :fromDate) AS date
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, :fromDate, :toDate) + 1)
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS n
        FROM sys.columns
    ) AS Numbers
)
SELECT
    FORMAT(d.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS label,
    ISNULL(SUM(abc.data1), 0) AS data1,
    ISNULL(SUM(abc.data2), 0) AS data2,
    ISNULL(SUM(abc.data3), 0) AS data3
FROM
    DateRange d
LEFT JOIN ABC abc ON
    CAST(abc.date AS DATE) = d.date
WHERE filtering1
    AND filtering2
    AND d.date >= :fromDate
    AND d.date <= :toDate
GROUP BY
    d.date
ORDER BY
    d.date ASC;

I am using this query in @Query annotation with nativeQuery=true
On Entity I am using this 2 annotation

@SqlResultSetMapping: To provide the mapping of the result to DTO
@NamedNativeQuery: To provide the naming of the query and result mapping

Code Level processing:
List<String> dateLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> data3 = new ArrayList<>();
    
                rawResults.forEach(result -> {
        dateLabels.add((String) result[0]);
        data1.add(((Number) result[1]).intValue());
        data2.add(((Number) result[2]).intValue());
        data3.add(((Number) result[3]).intValue());
    });


Why I am using this type of query ?

I want to show the data as 0 if no data is present for that particular date.


Size of the data we are talking about is in millions(can reach to billions).



How can I improve this query.
How to make API faster.
How to handle data projection properly.

I need the data in the ascending order based on date label.
Would appreciate any help in this.

You are doing a lot of unnecessary unboxing and re-boxing with Integer and int. Instead of data1.add(((Number) result[1]).intValue()); you can do data1.add((Integer) result[1]) if it's actually returned as an Integer. If not, give data1 the correct type. If you just want an int value, then use int[] in Mario Petrovic's answer. It's a micro-optimization that will only make a small difference to performance, but it's a good habit to get into to avoid unnecessary boxing/unboxing, to be aware of the difference between primitives and boxed values, and it also improves code readability

I appreciate your insights on this. Constraint is direct parsing isn't feasible here due to the value being retrieved from the database as a double, which caused errors when attempted directly. I’ll keep your points in mind, and I’m open to revisiting this in the future. But the main issue here is the time that it is taking and this will not address the issue I am facing.

First things first: get rid of that CAST() in the join. If you need to fix the table, then fix the table.

@TheImpaler can you please explain what is the benefit for removing the CAST()

A CAST() heavily limits the optimization options available to the engine. That would be the first step in the optimization, if you are interested in fast response times. Store the date as a DATE; storing it as a character string is just asking for trouble (and slowness).

Small improvement for java to minimize separate collections
Map<String, Integer[]> dateDataMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Object[] result : rawResults) {
    String dateLabel = (String) result[0];
    Integer data1Value = ((Number) result[1]).intValue();
    Integer data2Value = ((Number) result[2]).intValue();
    Integer data3Value = ((Number) result[3]).intValue();

    dateDataMap.put(dateLabel, new Integer[]{data1Value, data2Value, data3Value});
}


As I appreciate your answer, having HashMap not ensure the insertion order

Firstly, consider doing the joining after aggregation. As I understand, you need this joining to fill in the missing dates with zeros, right? From the output perspective, there should not be a difference if you do this after aggregation. However, you will significantly reduce the number of rows you need to join, resulting in performance improvements.
Secondly, consider partitioning the table by date. You said it yourself; you have millions and possibly billions of rows, which is a lot of data. Partitioning basically splits your table into smaller, more manageable parts. In your case, you could partition by month. When you run your query, the database will only load the rows from the partitions where your :dateFrom and :toDate fall.
Also, I'm not an expert on databases, but thinking from a data structure perspective, I believe that indexes can struggle with millions to billions of rows. Databases use B-trees to store indexes. So if you index by date, each key in the B-tree will be in a format like '2024-11-08'. Databases do not create duplicate keys but attach a new data pointer to the same key. In your case, if you have tens of thousands of rows per day, this means tens of thousands of pointers per key. Although there may be a relatively small number of keys in the B-tree (365 per year), your index will still be large in terms of memory. This can incur I/O penalties just from reading the index into memory. This could also potentially affect write operations, as the index needs to be updated during writes.
If you have the option to experiment, try both approaches and see which performs better. The downside of partitions is that they require a bit more effort to manage. The downside of indexes is that improvements are not guaranteed due to potential I/O costs.

I would like to understand more on your first point: "consider doing the joining after aggregation" Can you please explain it with  some example ? And thanks for the 2nd point "consider partitioning the table by date" I will surely try this.

To prevent needless changes, make use of the @SqlResultSetMapping. Instead of manually altering the results, return a list of DTOs straight from the repository.
Improved Query Technique
WITH DateRange AS (
    SELECT date 
    FROM PrecomputedDateRange 
    WHERE date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
)
SELECT
    FORMAT(d.date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS label,
    COALESCE(SUM(abc.data1), 0) AS data1,
    COALESCE(SUM(abc.data2), 0) AS data2,
    COALESCE(SUM(abc.data3), 0) AS data3
FROM
    DateRange d
LEFT JOIN ABC abc 
    ON abc.date = d.date -- Avoid casting
WHERE filtering1 AND filtering2
GROUP BY d.date
ORDER BY d.date ASC;

You can make better use of indexes and reduce computation by splitting date range computation from the primary query.
since I have not dealt with such large data I will hope that's helpful. and it's better to use Redis or Memecache for caching if this doesn't work.

PrecomputedDateRange <- Is this a table that contains the date ? In that case doing the direct join work rather than having it selected as WITH. This way we are costing the memory and we are talking about some good amount of data. Can you explain this SQL bit more ? Also as I have mentioned in the question @SqlResultSetMapping is already in place which will only remove the type casting code but having all the processing with the list still remains.

Since this will be long message i couldn't comment above so here's an explanation.
PrecomputedDateRange is a table, which contains all the dates that may occur in the future or past for your query. Hence you will never have a need for the generation of dates on the fly at execution time of queries. The WITH DateRange AS (.) CTE is used mostly for generating a set of dates on the fly, which consumes much more resources in case of dealing with a large amount of datasets. By precomputing the dates and storing them in a table, you avoid that computational overhead every time the query runs.

Why not use the WITH clause?

The SQL WITH clause has its uses but in your particular case it obliges the database to compute the date range for every execution of your query. This could involve a ROW_NUMBER() operation or other techniques to produce the series of dates. While this is fine for smaller datasets, it becomes pretty inefficient with large ranges since the database has to compute the entire sequence before it even starts processing the rest of the query.
But by using something like a precomputed table, as with PrecomputedDateRange, it ensures that you're not doing the date range computation over and over again. Instead, you do simple SELECT from already prepared dates stored in a table; in this case, it is extremely efficient, if you are working with large date ranges.

Memory Cost Consideration

You'd worry about the memory cost of storing these dates, but precomputing the date range is generally a one-time operation, and the cost in memory is quite low because you're just storing dates (not huge data sets). The gain in query performance from no longer having to compute the dates for each query is likely to more than offset the extra memory usage. Moreover, this table doesn't change very often, so it's okay to keep it static for a long time.

Better Query with Precomputed Dates

When you join on a precomputed date table, it executes faster because dates are already materialized. Without it if you're generating the dates dynamically (via ROW_NUMBER() or other means), then the database has to execute more steps to generate and join dates, which consumes more performance.
And finally @SqlResultSetMapping will help in mapping the query result to your DTO. Once more, though, this is not supposed to be the bottleneck and rather on the Java side with respect to data processing-the processing and aggregating after fetching into lists in Java, for example.
Of course, all this can be improved with an additional step-caching the results (for example, by using Redis or Memcached)-so that you store the processed aggregation results for the most frequently requested date ranges, further improving response times.
Conclusion:
PrecomputedDateRange is nothing but just a simple table that stores all the dates that might be needed to avoid generating dates on every query run.
The cost of keeping these dates in memory should usually be very low, so the performance improvement should be ample enough to outweigh this.
You can further accelerate the response time by caching results and also optimize the database query, particularly proper indexing and partitioning.
Hope it is all clear now!

If all months are quick to be loaded separately, but loading them together is slow, then you could UNION 6 similar queries to yours, each differing only in the date filter, so you would essentially have a query for each month and unioning the result.
If such is the case, then the explanation lies in your indexes, because if you have an index on the date's year, and month, like
create index idx_year_month on DateRange(YEAR(date), MONTH(date))

then your query would operate quickly on date filters. Of course, if there are lots of records to be loaded, then the actual load may be slow, but there is no way around that. Of course, you will need to look into filtering1 and filtering2, whatever they may be and see whether you can improve their performance too.
